# assemblyBinding probing is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

Sorry if this question have been asked already. But I have two websites, One have already webconfig. and I have added other site directory as virtual directory inside first site.

Like below, SampleSite is the Site Name  and I have added **Sample** as Virtual Directory from another location (c:\Sample). Now it has web subdirectory, in which Ver1.0 is another Site, which have its own dll and data.

[image]

Now I am launching SampleSite and after some event i want to launch Ver1.0 Site URL. When i launch Ver1.0 Site URL (localhost/SampleSite/Sample/web/VER1.0/default.aspx) then it gives me error of DLL function. That means DLL is not included here. So i added dll in Ver1.0 web.config as

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:Schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <probing privatePath="bin/Sample.Web.dll;" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

Bin is in Ver1.0 folder, which have Sample.Web.dll

But still its showing me same error from DLL function. So please help me to resolve this functionality.

Note: I tried to make the Ver1.0 as Application Directory then its resolving the problem. But i want to make this dynamic. Because Ver1.0 could be any Site in future.

**EDIT:**
Adding Inside folder of Ver1.0, Bin has Sample.Web.dll, which i want to include.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if i get your structure correctly. Could you place screenshot where the tree is expanded down to assemblies level?

Comment: Editied my question : added inside folders view

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you should place all **paths to subdirectories** that should be considered by Fusion engine while searching for assembly inside privatePath attribute value.

If you want to probe for libraries that are placed inside `Sample\web\Ver1.0\bin` and `Sample\web\Ver1.1\bin` subdirectories it should be like this:

```
<probing privatePath="Sample\web\Ver1.0\bin;Sample\web\Ver1.1\bin" />
```

Comment: If we have Sample folder outside of Main Root Site directory, then what could we do? is there any solution for that? In my case Root Site is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SampleSite and Other Site location is C:\Sample